# Will Coppersmith's method work for this bivariate modular polynomial shape?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations, lattices, cryptography

I have a bivariate modular polynomial of shape

$$f(x,y)=x^2y-g(x)\equiv 0\bmod q$$

where

1. $q=(2p-1)(2p+1)$ is a product of two primes $2p-1$ and $2p+1$,
2. $g(x)\in\mathbb Z[x]$ is of degree four and
3. $f(X,Y)\equiv 0\bmod q$ at integers $X,Y$ such that $|XY|<q^t$ where $t$ is any fixed number in $(0,1]$.

Is it possible to solve this shape using Coppersmith's method?

I looked at references and these state beyond univariate modular polynomial situation (such as bivariate modular polynomial here) Coppersmith's method works only heuristically because the generated polynomials provably not be algebraically independent for some polynomial shapes.

For a bivariate modular polynomial of above shape, will Coppersmith's method work? Can you explain?

Comment: You can try and see how it works in practice: https://github.com/maxale/coppersmith-algorithm

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I thought Coron's algorithm is for finding small solutions to $f(x,y)$ and not $f(x,y)\bmod M$?

Comment: In full generality it does solve modular polynomial equations, and this feature is supported by my fork that I linked above.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thank you.. I will have to try it.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I think actually in my case $X^4Y\approx  N^3q$ where and $q>>N^3$ where $N$ is a parameter. Since modulus $M\approx q^2$, I think this gives $X^4Y<q^2$. Would the scheme fail for magnitude reasons or it will not fail for magnitude reasons (but still has possibility to fail for other reasons such as not enough algebraically independent polynomial production)?

Comment: (I can choose $q\gg N^t$ where t is any fixed natural number).

Comment: Is this in Python?? 'P.<x,y> = PolynomialRing(ZZ)
    pol = P( pol(x,y) )' does not work for me.

Comment: It's SageMath code https://www.sagemath.org/

For theoretical bounds, please see original Coron's paper linked there.